# Honeypot spam trap conflicts with browsers auto-fill feature

Tags: javascript, spam, spam-prevention, honeypot

As you may know, Chrome does not support:autocomplete="off", autocomplete="nope", autocomplete="false" or even autocomplete="new-password" any longer.

That means, from time to time, I do get reports that honeypot traps are preventing users from submitting forms, since the trap input is being auto-filled, even if not shown.

The practice for setting the trap is wrapping a TEXT input with a display:none; element, so spam bots won't be able to figure its really hidden (unless they are smarter and they usually aren't), and if this input has contents, you won't allow the submission to go through, as the field supposed to be hidden and empty for regular users.

What's your practice in using honeypot traps while still having browsers ignoring the demand for auto-complete or auto-fill by using the above arributes?

Comment: Tell them to stop using Chrome, they seem to have no interest in fixing this stupid behavior. For years their answer has been 'turn off autocomplete' but then they took that away too! First reported back in 2012 -> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132135

Answer (score 4):

My current solution (October 2022) for a honeypot field looks like this:

- Move the input field out of the visible area using css
- Avoid name attributes that Chrome looks for when autofilling, like email, address, etc.
- Do not wrap the honeypot input element with other elements that contain such keywords in their label or in name attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FormFind (which analyzes a page's source code and extracts the 'action' parameter and the input tags will find hidden fields. Hidden fields will not stop a spambot.

FormFind will find all the fields on a form from the HTML source code. And once you find the input fields - and the 'action' parameter (which FormFind does find) - its easy to use CURL or WGET to 'submit' the form.

Although reCAPTCHA will help with spambots, the only technique that I have found (and what I use in my solution) is to have some JavaScript code that will change the form's action parameter on a onclick/onfocus event. And if you put a delay in the JS function that changes the action parameter, that's a bonus spambot blocker.

Using JS to change things (or even to fill in a hidden field, if you insist on using one) is a good technique.  CUSL and WGET cannot process JS code. (There was an open source project that claimed to be able to process JS code, but it was abandoned a couple of years ago.)

The JS trick is what I use in my contact form at my free [FormSpammerTrap.com](https://www.formspammertrap.com) site. Code is free and open source. And the contact form there uses my technique. Have not gotten any spam via a spambot (automated process) from there. And I am working on a newer version that will add delays to even further block spammers.

Anyone is welcome to request the code to try it out. No charge. No fees. No advertising. No $$ benefit to me, other than how I use it on my sites to block spam.

So, using hidden fields to stop spambots is not going to work well. You have to have more layers of defense against them. Using JS code techniques is another layer that will help block almost all spambots. (There's no 100% solution, but I think mine is close - and it's been around for a couple of years.)

Answer (score 0):

I removed the name variable from the input tag and this resolved the issue of the hidden honey pot fields getting autofilled...